# Symfony2 dynamic queryBuilder

Tags: symfony, dynamic, doctrine, query-builder

I'm making a tool in which a user can view data from an entity, where they can choose what data and how they see the records.

I created a form with two date fields (start and end) and a list of fields that correspond to data counts and sums of the entity.

My question is:

How I can create a dynamically QueryBuilder that allows me to add fields based on what the user wants to see?

**EDIT** for [Symfony2 dynamic queryBuilder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32380659/symfony2-dynamic-querybuilder?noredirect=1#comment52632484_32380659)

```
public function reportData($fields, $dateStart, $dateFinish)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Entity');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('e');

    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        switch($field)
        {
            case 'totalResults':
                $query->setect('SUM(e.id) AS '.$field);
                break;
        }
    }
    $query->addWhere('e.dateStart >= :dateStart');
    $query->addWhere('e.dateFinish <= :dateFinish');
    ...
```

Comment: Did you have a look at this ? http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

Comment: This is for form builder not for queryBuilder :(

Comment: Yes, indeed. My bad ! Can you pass an array of options to your entity repository ?

Comment: Yes, ill add to original message my function in the entityRepo

Comment: Its just an idea, but i thunk is not the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ? You store all your select queries in an array, then pass the array to the query builder after testing each of your fields.

```
public function reportData($fields, $dateStart, $dateFinish)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager()
        ->getRepository('AcmeBundle:Entity');
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder('e');

    $select_array = array();

    foreach($fields as $field)
    {
        switch($field)
        {
            case 'totalResults':
                $select_array[] = 'SUM(e.id) AS '.$field;
                break;
        }
    }

    $query->select($select_array);
    $query->addWhere('e.dateStart >= :dateStart');
    $query->addWhere('e.dateFinish <= :dateFinish');
    ....
```

Comment: Uhms, no, this is the same as im doing but chaging select for addSelect `$query->addSelect('SUM(d.id)');`

Comment: What I need is to know whether this is the best method to obtain the filtered records or is there something more standart

Comment: Personally I have the same approach as you, I don't see any other way to do this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, ill try to do by this way or wait for more ideas :) Thanks for your time!

Comment: I think you mean `andWhere` rather than `addWhere`

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you want to keep on adding the

> Select Fields

based upon the conditions.
So, the solution is simple.

You can use,

```
$queryBuilder->addSelect();
```

[See Doctrine Query Builder Documentation](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Answer (score 0):

I would do a regular full query then filter it into a not doctrine object (dao/dto) then display it.

This way you can do the complex and optimized query first, then filter the result on whatever you want, even if it's not related to the query itself